# Error says "value of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'observe'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is the line I'm getting an error on:

```
databaseHandle = ref.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.postData.append("")
    })
```

Below is all of the code...

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet
    var tableView: UITableView!

        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
            var databaseHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle ?

                var postData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self



        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, withBlock: {
            (snapshot) in
            self.postData.append("")
        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func JumpTabLive(sender: AnyObject) {

        tabBarController ? .selectedIndex = 1
    }

    @IBAction func JumpTabLocal(sender: AnyObject) {

        tabBarController ? .selectedIndex = 2
    }

    @IBAction func JumpTabOnline(sender: AnyObject) {

        tabBarController ? .selectedIndex = 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {

        return postData.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell")
        cell ? .textLabel ? .text = postData[indexPath.row]

        return cell!


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct block of code should be:

```
    databaseHandle = ref.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        self.postData.append("")
    })
```

What do you notice between this correct code and your code above? See the completion block. Mine is **with** and yours is **withBlock**. When coding, use the power of auto-complete. For instance, you type this block of code, and the Xcode now asks you what to do with the completion block of the Firebase code. You should just double click on the completion block and Xcode will fix everything for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed withBlock to with but am still getting the same error message

Comment: Using the auto-complete suggestion I was able to get it to work. The code ended up being: databaseHandle = ref.child("Posts").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            self.postData.append("") ...thank you for the help!

Comment: Oh! Probably we're using different versions of the Firebase SDK. Anyways, just use the auto completion/suggestion of Xcode in the future. :D Glad you solved it now. Can you select this as the answer to your post?